# py2exe fails to create .exe due to missing modules

Tags: python, py2exe

I've been programming a python program that uses resources from a precompiled Python 2.7 binary. I'm using MIT's Name Entity Recognition tool found [here](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE). I'm trying to make my .py into a .exe using py2exe but the .exe is never created. Instead, I get the following errors:

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'ElementC14N', '_sysconfigdata', 'cElementTree', 
'elementtree.ElementTree', 'lxml.etree']

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

   OLEAUT32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
   USER32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
   IMM32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
   COMDLG32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll
   COMCTL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\COMCTL32.dll
   ADVAPI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
   CRYPT32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
   WS2_32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
   GDI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
   VERSION.dll - C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
   ole32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
```

How do I resolve these errors so the .exe file is created?

Comment: What do mean by "but the .exe never works"? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: There could be lots of reasons, if you have a log or trace-back of exception thats what we need in order to help you.

Comment: @ChadNouis py2exe creates a .exe but the .exe doesn't run.

Comment: What does your setup.py look like? Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445262/py2exe-the-following-modules-appear-to-be-missing) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524483/modules-appear-to-be-missing-py2exe)